# android studio app crashes after calling multiple comands

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arduino

I want to build an app to control my arduino car. After calling multiple comands to control my car, the bluetooth disconnects and i receive that error: `E/Error: in forward:Broken pipe`. What does it mean? the car remains on the last command i pressed after the app disconnects.

After this `Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()` the car doesn't take any commands.

CarControl Class:

```
String address = null;
private ProgressDialog progress;
BluetoothAdapter myBt = null;
BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private boolean isBtConnected = false;

private void resetConn()
{
    myBt = null;
    btSocket = null;
    isBtConnected = false;
    new connectbt().execute();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    disconnect();
}

static final UUID myUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bot);
    //  Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    f1=  findViewById(R.id.up1);
    l1= findViewById(R.id.left1);
    r1= findViewById(R.id.right1);
    b1= findViewById(R.id.back1);
    st1= findViewById(R.id.stop1);
    linef=findViewById(R.id.linef1);
    auto_button = findViewById(R.id.button_auto);

    Intent newint = getIntent();
    address = newint.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRAADD);
    new  connectbt().execute();

   


private void disconnect()
{
    if (btSocket!=null)
    {
        try
        {
            btSocket.close(); //close connection
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            msg("Error");
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            resetConn();
        }
    }
    finish(); //return to the first layout

}

// fast way to call Toast
private void msg(String s)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private class connectbt extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>  // UI thread
{
    private boolean ConnectSuccess = true; //if it's here, it's almost connected

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(CarControl.this, "Connecting...", "Please wait!!!");  //show a progress dialog
    }



    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... devices) //while the progress dialog is shown, the connection is done in background
    {
        try
        {
            if (btSocket == null || !isBtConnected)
            {
                myBt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();//get the mobile bluetooth device

                BluetoothDevice dispositivo = myBt.getRemoteDevice(address);//connects to the device's address and checks if it's available
                btSocket = dispositivo.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(myUUID);//create a RFCOMM (SPP) connection
                BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().cancelDiscovery();
                btSocket.connect();//start connection
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            ConnectSuccess = false;//if the try failed, you can check the exception here
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) //after the doInBackground, it checks if everything went fine
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (!ConnectSuccess)
        {
            msg("Connection Failed. Is it a SPP Bluetooth? Try again.");
            finish();
        }
        else
        {

            msg("Connected.");
            isBtConnected=true;
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does the car perhaps get too far away from the phone and the Bluetooth connection gets broken?

Comment: also can you put the code on the Arduino?

Comment: I don t think this is the problem, because i tried to control it close to the phone and still have this issue

Answer (score 0):

This means that the memory limit for the program is 6mb and the program throws the error when the memory limit has been reached as it cannot accept further commands. I suppose there is no direct way to increase this limit.